# In a world where the four seasons reflect the four elements, what is the season of Earth?

Tags: alternate-worlds, classical-elements

In one world I am building, the four seasons are composed of the four elements.

It would probably go in this direction:
Water>Earth>Fire>Wind>Water

```
The season of Fire is dry and hot.
Between the season of Fire and Wind is a time of lightning and prophecy.
The season of Wind is windy and chaotic.
Between the season of Wind and Water is a time of storms and seafaring.
The season of Water is cold and wet.
```

I am having difficulty, however, coming up with the season of Earth, and the "Solstices" adjacent to Fire and Water.

What would be the trademarks for the Season of Earth with this kind of example?

Comment: This question belongs on the main site. It is also pretty much based on opinions.

Comment: This question is entirely opinion based, and should be closed as such.

Comment: Watch Avatar the Last Air Bender. Earth's season was spring if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The season of Earth is fertility.**

In the season of Earth, she does her thing keeping us alive.  Fields!  Flowers!  Baby animals!  Green!  Plus you have to have some season to grow food or people will starve.  You can't eat lighting and chaos.

As I understand it Earth would be roughly analogous to spring, fire to summer, wind to autumn and water to winter.  California has seasons like that.  So summer solstice would be the earth to fire transition and winter the wind to water transition.  On earth to fire, the fields burn.  Wind to water means the big storms.

Comment: This is what I was thinking.  The season of life.

Comment: To match the OP's pattern, this would be "calm and orderly."  The transition from Water would be "wet and orderly, a time of fog and planting."  The transition into fire would be "calm and hot, a time of death and harvest."

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how this answer in any way differs from my own.  It came after mine, is essentially the same answer, yet has more votes and is accepted.  Either I seem to be missing something about this SE site that is extremely subtle and nuanced, or WB users like answers posted by someone with far more WB rep.

Comment: @Attackfarm - I am sorry ours are so similar.  You must have posted yours while I was typing up mine.  I hope that it is not rep that gave mine more votes.  I think it is that bold face title.

Comment: @Willk I don't blame you.  I honestly assume there must be some sort of weird nuance I'm not getting.  Maybe it is the bold title?  I usually am on another SE site where the differences in votes is a little easier to spot than this, so I was a bit surprised there was such a difference in results over such similar answers.  I thought maybe there was something a little WorldBuilding.SE specific I wasn't seeing here.

Answer (score 3):

```
Between the season of Water and Earth is a time of floods and hope.
The season of Earth is temperate and bountiful.
Between the season of Earth and Fire is a time of preparation and hoarding.
```

Basically, I see Earth in your system as a very Spring-like season after the cold and wet season of Water.  That water and the warming of leaving the season of Water would bring significant plant and animal growth.  As they leave the season of the Earth, animals and sentients would be preparing for the harsher seasons by gathering as much of the seasonal resources as they can.

Answer (score 1):

Aristotle described the elements in terms of temperature and moisture.

From the Wikipedia page on the Four Elements.

> In his On Generation and Corruption, Aristotle related each of the four elements to two of the four sensible qualities:
>   Fire is both hot and dry.
>   Air is both hot and wet (for air is like vapor, ἀτμὶς).
>   Water is both cold and wet.
>   Earth is both cold and dry.

In this world, the earth season is cold and dry. This isn't a climate where snow is frequent, so the cold season is characterized by a lot of bare ground where nothing grows. After the wet season, there is growth again.